# Rails upvote/downvote using Ajax and acts_as_votable

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, acts-as-votable

Still fairly new to Rails. I used the acts_as_votable gem to create upvote and upvote buttons to allow users to upvote/downvote jokes, but I can't make them change from upvote / downvote (and vice versa) and update the counter each time they click without refreshing the page. I tried following other kind-of-similar answers without luck. Here's what I tried to implement.

Joke Model

```
acts_as_votable
```

User Model

```
acts_as voter
```

Routes.rb is

```
resources :jokes do
member do
  get "like" => "jokes#upvote"
  get "unlike" => "jokes#downvote"
end
end
```

Jokes Controller is

```
#upvote from user
def upvote
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
    @joke.upvote_from current_user
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
end

#downvote from user
def downvote
    @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
    @joke.downvote_from current_user
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js { render :layout => false }
    end
end
```

My view:

```
<div class="votes">
<%= link_to like_joke_path(@joke), method: :get, remote: true, class:     'like_joke' do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        <span class="badge vote_count"><%= @joke.get_upvotes.size %></span>
    </button>
<% end %>

<%= link_to unlike_joke_path(@joke), method: :get, remote: true, class: 'unlike_joke' do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        <span class="badge voute_count"><%= @joke.get_downvotes.size %></span>
    </button>
<% end %>
</div>
```

like.js.erb:

```
$('.like_joke').bind('ajax:success', function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript     @joke.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
   $(this).closest('.like_joke').hide();
   $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unlike",  unlike_joke_path(@joke), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_joke' %>');
});
```

and finally unlike.js.erb:

```
$('.unlike_joke').bind('ajax:success', function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript @joke.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
   $(this).closest('.unlike_joke').hide();
   $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Like", like_joke_path(@joke), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'like_joke' %>');
});
```

Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<div class="votes">
<a class="like_joke" data-remote="true" data-method="get" href="/jokes/11-cat-joke-title/like">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
        <span class="badge vote_count">0</span>
    </button>
</a>
<a class="unlike_joke" data-remote="true" data-method="get" href="/jokes/11-cat-joke-title/unlike">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>
        <span class="badge voute_count">1</span>
     </button>
</a></div>
```

When I look at the js console, I get an internal server error at jquery.js?body=1:9665 which is xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null );

It seems like I'm close, but I think I've messed up something in my views and js. Can someone show me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at the code you've provided... the code is coloured for what is inside and outside of a string... and you'll notice this line here:

```
 $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unlike",  unlike_joke_path(@joke), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_joke' %>');
```

gets coloured so that parts of the code are inside the string... but parts aren't (scroll to the right to see it, it's near the end).

I don't know for sure that this is your error, but you probably should consider changing this to:

```
 $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unlike",  unlike_joke_path(@joke), remote: true, method: :get, class: "unlike_joke" %>');
```

if only to clear up ambiguity. (also check the other lines for similar issues)

---

Ok, I think the problem is this.
once you have clicked like... you go to the action for liking (which, BTW you should probably call 'like' instead of 'upvote' for consistency)>
Then you render the like.js.

at this point you want the js to actually update the like-count etc.
You already have the javascript and you just want to run it right away.
You don't need to bind it to ajax success... you already have succeeded. So your like.js should just contain the bare javascript to actually update the screen right now eg:

```
var like_joke = $('.unlike_joke');
like_joke.parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript     @joke.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
like_joke.closest('.like_joke').hide();
like_joke.closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unlike",  unlike_joke_path(@joke), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_joke' %>');
```

Note: untested and there may be bugs, but you get the idea. Don;'t put a function that will get called on ajax success or it will sit there waiting for some other success to happen. Success has already happened... now just go and do the thing :)

Also note: there's a typo here:

```
   <span class="badge voute_count"><%= @joke.get_downvotes.size %></span>
```

should be

```
   <span class="badge vote_count"><%= @joke.get_downvotes.size %></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I've added the rendered HTML as well as the error that I get from the js console with the line of code that it's getting tripped up on.

Comment: @GregSéguin ok, updated with what I *think* might be going on. have a go with that and see.

Answer (score 0):

A better way...

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :jokes do
  match :vote, via: [:post, :delete], on: :member
end

#app/controllers/jokes_controller.rb
class JokesController < ApplicationController
   def vote
       @joke = Joke.find(params[:id])
       if request.post?
           @joke.upvote_from current_user
       elsif request.delete?
           @joke.downvote_from current_user
       end
       respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to :back }
          format.js
       end
   end
end
```

Make a single `partial` view:

```
#app/views/jokes/_vote.html.erb
<% voted   = current_user.voted_for? joke %>
<% styling = voted ? "" : "un" %>
<% arrow   = voted ? "up" : "down" %>
<% method  = voted ? :delete : :post %>

<%= link_to vote_joke_path(joke), method: method, remote: true, class: '#{styling}like_joke', id: joke.id do %>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" aria-label="Left Align">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-<%= arrow %>"></i>
        <span class="badge vote_count"><%= joke.get_upvotes.size %></span>
    </button>
<% end %>

#app/views/jokes/show.html.erb
<%= render partial: "vote", locals: { joke: @joke } %>
```

This way, when you invoke `vote.js.erb` from your `JokesController`, you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/jokes/vote.js.erb
$("<%=j @joke.id %>").html("<%=j render partial: "jokes/vote", locals: { joke: @joke } %>");
```

Comment: This may well work - but the OP is trying to learn how to do this and will be served better for figuring out what went wrong with what they tried rather than being handed a solution as a fait accompli

Comment: I'll delete if the OP doesn't like it